# Need local transforms, from global transforms (C#) Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a missile effect, when I fired to global gameobject as a target, it works fine, but I fired to any gameobject which is in some parent, it doesn't work fine, it goes to an unknown position. Here is my code to move missile to the target.

m_target  =  is my target
m_targetOffset  =  if to need to add any offset, by default it is (0,0,0)

```
protected override void goToTarget()
{       

    m_direction = (m_target.position + m_targetOffset - transform.position).normalized * m_distanceInfluence.Evaluate(1 - (m_target.position + m_targetOffset - transform.position).magnitude / m_searchRange);
    m_rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(m_rigidbody.velocity + m_direction * m_guidanceIntensity, m_rigidbody.velocity.magnitude);

    if (m_rigidbody.velocity != Vector3.zero)
        transform.LookAt(m_rigidbody.velocity);
}
```

Comment: when you get m_target - this will be your key..

Comment: I am getting target through raycast
if (Physics.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction * 1000 ,out hit, 1500.0f , layerMask) ) 
     {
      bullet_target = hit.point;
      hit_game_object = hit.transform.gameObject;
      hit_transform = hit.transform;
     }

Comment: so m_target should have a m_target.transform.position, not just .position..

Comment: yeah, thanks , it solve..:-),

Comment: Could we get this as an answer so we can mark this as solved?

Comment: yes of course, it solved my problem, we can mark this as solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, it probably doesnt work because m_target is the gameobject, not the transform, therefore instead of m_target.position, its m_target.transform.position